# Ionic CLI error - Error: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null on terminal

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

im new to ionic and angular js. I was building my app succesfully using the ionic cli, now I am having an issue while building for ios which was working fine since yesterday. I have updated ionic, create new project but still cannot run this command "ionic build ios", however "ionic serve" works successfully. Please note that I am using a mac and these command were working fine before. Grateful if someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Hi there! Whats your node/npm version?

Comment: Hello, i have node v5.7.0 installed

Comment: Got exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people who are having this issue, it looks like it's a bug in Node 5.7.0, to be fixed in 5.7.1:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/815
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10675
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5393

Downgrading your Node version or updating when 5.7.1 comes out should resolve the issue.

Comment: changing node versions does not fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just ran into the same issue, while building on iOS (Android worked fine). It seems that it has got to do with config.xml .

I had to put `<access origin="mailto: ... launch-external="true"/>` under `<platform name="android">` and the issue was solved.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem just move all `<access origin="file:..."` or  `<allow-navigation href="file:.." />` under `<platform name="android">` in your config.xml